# B+ tree as an index structure in in-memory databases: how to avoid rebalancing?

Tags: b-tree, in-memory-database

I have just read the paper "An efficient B+-tree design for main-memory database systems with strong access locality" by Pei-Lun Suei and his colleagues, where implementing B+ trees as an index structure with auxiliary-trees is suggested to avoid overhead of multiple rebalances. Now I am looking for other approaches which are implementing B+ trees in in-memory databases in a different way. What other approaches exist or more specifically:

How is it possible to avoid the overhead of rebalancing B+ trees in in-memory databases when using B+ trees as an index structure?

Comment: Shouldn't your question be which data structure to use for a specific use case rather than how to alter a particular one to fit your needs?

Comment: Although I know other data structures might be doing a better job, I am particularly interested in other approaches using B+ trees.

Comment: It's just that - as far as I am aware - the need to rebalance is a fundamental property of B+ trees.

Comment: I think you are right. Nevertheless there are approaches -like the one I mentioned in my post- that are trying to avoid rebalancing or make rebalancing itself more efficient. I was hoping to learn more about these approaches (first of all, I would like to know which approaches even exist).

Comment: Is the paper available somewhere for non-academics? I found only the usual pay-through-the-nose sites; the only free site ([freepaperdownload.us](http://www.freepaperdownload.us/1752/Article2498245.htm)) reeks of fish. The [publisher's site](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025513000029) shows a couple illustrations as teasers, from which it would appear that the paper holds little of interest regarding theory and/or practice of B-Trees (reduce the cost of insertions by routing them to a lookaside auxiliary tree which gets merged into the main tree periodically, doh).

Comment: As far as I know there is unfortunately no free access to this paper (I would strongly recommend to listen to your instinct and not use any strange looking sites..). You are right though, there is not much information given about the theory or practice of B-trees.